# Parallel stream finishes before the task is done

Tags: java, parallel-processing, thread-safety, java-stream

I use this method to initialize an ArrayList with a default value:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> createArrayList(int size, int defaultValue)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(size);
    IntStream.range(0, size ).parallel().forEach(i->{arrayList.add(defaultValue);});

    return arrayList;
}
```

Surprisingly, if I check the size of the return array with unit test, it not fixed number, and almost always it smaller than the requested size.

If I remove the `parallel()` its size is always as requested.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Because an arraylist is not a thread safe collection and you are trying to insert elements concurrently in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Of course* it's smaller, you are adding multiple elements from multiple Threads to a non thread-safe `ArrayList` (that does re-size when elements can't fill in it's original size).

You could do that simpler with:

```
Collections.nCopies(i, defaultValue);
```

Comment: And being smaller is only one possible outcome of the invalid multi-threaded `ArrayList` modification. Another possibility would be spurious `null` elements in the result list. `nCopies` is the way to go when an immutable list is an acceptable result. If the OP really needs an `ArrayList`, it can be created as simple as `new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(i, defaultValue))`…

Answer (score 0):

Use thread-safe CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<Integer> createArrayList(int size, int defaultValue)
{
    List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(size);
    IntStream.range(0, size ).parallel().forEach(i->{list.add(defaultValue);});

    return list;
}
```

Comment: `side-effects`... you are breaking this, even if you do this in a "safer" way

Comment: yep, totally aware of that.. just giving OP something immediately usable..

Comment: if you are, why not give him a proper `map(...).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList(size)))`?

Comment: There might be solutions being even more inefficient, but you have to try really hard to find them…